# Sample Browser Visual Studio (2012) Extension does not show samples

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions

After downloading, when i click "open" button, i get this message:

This command needs a single parameter that contains 9 pipe-separated parts. Only 10 part(s) detected in the given parameter.

Does anybody know how to fix it?